# Cucumber 'After' Hook not working?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

Cucumber 'After' Hook not working?

I have a DriverFactory class which performs the setup etc as listed below however once all steps have been executed the 'Cucumber After' method dosnt seem to work which is housed in the DriverFactory?

I want a master hooks class 'Before' 'After' etc etc which will stop code duplication within Step files

```
public class DriverFactory  {
protected WebDriver driver;
protected BasePage basePage;
protected LoginPage loginPage;

public WebDriver getDriver() {
    if(driver == null) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\other\\chromedriver.exe");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        this.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    return this.driver;
}

public WebDriver returnDriver() {
    return this.driver;
}


@After
public void test() throws Throwable {
    this.driver.close();
    this.driver.quit();
}
```

}

```
public class LoginSteps {
DriverFactory driverFactory = new DriverFactory();
WebDriver driver = driverFactory.getDriver();

@Given("^User navigates to the \"([^\"]*)\" website$")
public void user_navigates_to_the_website(String url) throws Throwable {
    BasePage basePage = new BasePage(driver);
    basePage.loadUrl(url);
}

@And("^User entered the \"([^\"]*)\" username$")
public void user_entered_the_username(String username) throws Throwable {
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    loginPage.setUsername(username);
}
```

Comment: I am using 1.2.4 version for both **cucumber-java** and **cucumber-junit** and it works fine for me. I don't see any issue with global hooks.

Comment: @Gaurang Shah are you able to extend the class which has the Global Hooks? for example classA extends classGlobalHooks?

Comment: I have never needed that, so I don't know. you can give it a try.

Comment: @Gaurang Shah but how would the Master Hooks know when to execute if there in a seperate class?

Comment: they don't need to. as soon as they are in the classpath. Same place where other java files is, Cucumber figures it out.

Comment: @Gaurang Shah i have tried this but didnt work, do you have an example?

Comment: I wrote this blog post way back,hope it still works. 
http://www.automationtesting.co.in/2015/12/jvm-cucumber-hooks-part-1.html

Comment: @Gaurang Shah can you go to private chat when you get time?

Comment: @Gaurang Shah thanks read the blog, is there a reason why you have made the driver instance static?

Comment: as I said, the post is told, I don't remember everything, if it's working try to change the access specifier and see what happens. also, if it's working with latest version of cucumber then update that as well here.

Comment: @Gaurang Shah thanks for your help

Comment: is the solution working?

Comment: @Gaurang Shah havent tried it yet my only concern is that hooks and the pages both extend a class with no hooks?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - my @Before hook was working but my @After hook wasn't. This turned out to be due to a simple import problem - probably caused by choosing the wrong option when Intellij offered me the list of imports. I had chosen the junit.After class rather than the cucumber.api.Java.After class:

```
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java8.En;
import org.junit.After;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

Comment: I have the same problem but I am importing the right annotation
io.cucumber.java.After; So what could be the issue in my case?